# How to identify all the log files under being created using log4j under /var/log

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, log-rotation

I am trying to identify and list all the log files which are being created with log4j.
I want to then assert if all these log files have the rotation policies defined in the log4j2.xml files.

What will be the best way to list these files which are created using log4j?